# lua does not see a defined global variable... attempt to index global ... (a nil value)

Tags: lua, global, null

I am sure I am missing something ridiculously simple, but I stared at this long enough to ask for your help.  I am trying to write the simplest of all loggers, and when I'm trying to run it, it's not seeing the global variable (that I (think) I declare!).  I am an "advanced" beginner in lua, so silly mistakes are not as common, but still do happen in my case.  Please, tell me what I'm missing here!

Here's the logger code, and I'm testing it within the script....

```
local type, pairs, table, tostring, io, os, print = type, pairs, table, tostring, io, os, print
local file
LEVELS = {}
LEVELS ["ERROR"] = 0
LEVELS ["WARN"] = 1
LEVELS ["INFO"] = 2
LEVELS ["DEBUG"] = 3
print (LEVELS.WARN)
local level

function init (outputFile, debugLevel)
  level = debugLevel
  file = io.open(outputFile, "a")
  local ret
  if (file == nil) then ret = false else ret = true end
  return ret
end

function warn (message)
   if level ~= nil and level >= LEVELS.WARN and file ~= nil then
     log(message)
   end
end
function log (message)
   local timestamp = os.date()

    file:write(timestamp..' - '..message..'\n')
    file:flush()
end

function deInit ()
   file:close()
end

init ("testInsideLogger.lua", 3)
warn("HI")
deInit()
```

What I get in the output:

Print right after the declaration of LEVELS works, prints out 1.

But when I call the warn("HI") method, I get

attempt to index global 'LEVELS' (a nil value).

WHY???

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Please try to produce a smaller test case. I think you could get rid of most of the functions and variables in the program and still get the same error.

Comment: There is a syntax error at the end a useless `end` token). If you get rid of it then the code runs fine.]

Comment: My bad - the last end token was added when I was writing up the code here.  It's not there in the actual program.  I also removed all the unnecessary code.

Comment: The simplified version also runs perfectly fine for me.

Comment: But I get the attempt to index global 'LEVELS' (a nil value)

Comment: BTW, I added a print (LEVELS.WARN) right after the declaration, and it prints just fine.  But when calling LEVELS.WARN inside the warn method, it does not see it...

Comment: The example you posted doesn't reproduce the issue you have. It runs fine. Add the same `print(LEVELS.WARN)` inside the `warn` method and run exactly the same script, then show the output.

Comment: maybe you redefine the global LEVELS in another function and forgot the `local` keyword there? you mentioned having removed "unnecessary code", but I suspect the error is in there, maybe you can post your whole code? (also, I strongly recommend against using globals for something like this) also, if you redefine LEVELS inside `testInsideLogger.lua`, it could also cause problems...

Comment: If you run the code that you posted (exactly a s posted) do you see the error? If not try adding the code you removed and remove a bit then rerun, if problem goes away restore a bit of removed code etc. If you still have problem then update for question with new info, else problem gone then close this question (delete it or post answer to your own question).